# Determining color of ball from urn with condition that the two next balls are white

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

One ball is removed from an urn containing $a$ white and $b$ black balls.
To determine the color of the removed ball, two more balls are drawn. What
is the probability that a black ball has been removed at the beginning, if both balls
drawn afterwards are white?

Comment: You just calculated P(both white | black first). For P(both white), you also need to consider the possibility that white was drawn first.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the required conditional probability by using notation of colored balls drawn in sequence, and counting number of ways rather than probability (since the denominator will remain the same)

$P(\text{black first} \mid\text{both white afterwards})$

$={P(BWW)\over  P (BWW) +P(WWW)}$

$= {n(BWW)\over n(BWW)+ n(WWW)}$

$= \dfrac {b a  (a-1)}{b a (a-1) + a (a-1) (a-2)} =\boxed{ \dfrac{b}{b+a-2}}$

Answer (score 2):

Remove the two whites, then you pull a black with probability $\frac{b}{a+b-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We apply Bayes theorem to calculate the probability:

$$P(\text{black first} \mid\text{both white afterwards})=\dfrac{P(\text{both white afterwards }\mid\text{black first})\cdot P(\text{black first})}{P(\text{both white afterwards})}$$.

Now the individual probabilities. The probability that black will be drawn first is
$$
P(\text{black first})=\frac{b}{a+b}
$$
because there are a total of $a+b$ balls from which $b$ are black. The probability that both are white afterwards means that there are only $a+b-1$ balls left from the $a+b$ balls:
$$
P(\text{both white afterwards} \mid \text{black first})=\frac{a}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-1}{a+b-2}.
$$
Finally we calculate
$$
P(\text{both white afterwards})=\frac{b}{a+b}\frac{a}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-1}{a+b-2}+\frac{a}{a+b}\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-2}{a+b-2} 
$$
Thus we have
$$
\dfrac{\frac{a}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-1}{a+b-2}\cdot \frac{b}{a+b}}{\frac{b}{a+b}\frac{a}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-1}{a+b-2}+\frac{a}{a+b}\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}\cdot \frac{a-2}{a+b-2}}= \dfrac{b}{b+a-2}.
$$